# How to convert this string to Date? || How to read/write date in mongodb?

Tags: java, string, mongodb, date, nosql

Lets say I have a class User. A user got a name, gender, ..., born. When I got an userobject I can insert that in the database. Thats fine. There is just a problem with date. Im trying this:

```
String json = "{'name': '" + user.getName() + "', 'born': '" + user.getBorn() + "'}";
DBObject o = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
myCollection.insert(o);
```

`user.getBorn()` is returning a Date, but in the database it is a string. So if Im reading it I get something like `Fri Sep 05 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 1980` as a string and thats not good :) I would like have a Date. So there is maybe more the one option(?) Maybe I could convert this DateString somehow to Date? Or maybe I could insert the document without a string? Thank you for any help!

Edit: ok Renato said I could use simpledateformat. And whats about the other option? How to put it as a Date() in the db?

Comment: When you say "in the database it is a string" - why? Why not make it a date there as well?

Comment: Well thats the other question there: how to write the Date() as a Date() into the db ;) Dont know the solution in mongodb. Is it even possible to write a Date() as a Date() in this json style?

Comment: you're contradicting yourself: "When I got an userobject I can insert that in the database. Thats fine. There is just a problem with date.", so you do *know* how to save a Date() as a Date(), but you convert user.getBorn() to String (json) and then save to mongo. What do you expect mongo to do, save it as a Date? every time you pass a String you expect mongo to read your mind and figure out the type? it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Sry milan dont understand what you really want ^^ Renato and Wes Freeman did answer the question perfect. But thank you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use the `BasicDBObjectBuilder` like so:

```
DBObject o = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
  .add("name", user.getName())
  .add("born", user.getBorn())
  .get();
myCollection.insert(o);
```

This will store the born value as a BSON date.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a simple date dd-MM-yyyy or whatever, using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Given that you just want to store the date the user was born, which usually means day, month, and year, storing it as a String makes sense (you could also convert it to a long with Date.getTime() and reconverting the long to a Date Object using the constructor - new Date(long), this would save you some bytes but the information in the DB becomes far from clear )

```
    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // convert a date to a String
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date());
    // this prints 2012-01-18
    System.out.println(dateString);

    try {
        Date today = formatter.parse(dateString);
        // this prints Wed Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2012
        System.out.println(today);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // string was invalid
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```